# Spring REST API validation and error handling

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-validator

I'm using Spring along with Spring boot to make a REST API.
I'm almost done implementing my first endpoints but I have a problem with validation and error handling.

I first found a way to do the validation by creating a `@ControllerAdvice` class as follow:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestErrorHandler {

    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Autowired
    public RestErrorHandler(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ValidationErrorDTO processValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
        List<FieldError> fieldErrors = result.getFieldErrors();

        return processFieldErrors(fieldErrors);
    }

    private ValidationErrorDTO processFieldErrors(List<FieldError> fieldErrors) {
        ValidationErrorDTO dto = new ValidationErrorDTO();

        for (FieldError fieldError: fieldErrors) {
            String localizedErrorMessage = resolveLocalizedErrorMessage(fieldError);
            dto.addFieldError(fieldError.getField(), localizedErrorMessage);
        }

        return dto;
    }

    private String resolveLocalizedErrorMessage(FieldError fieldError) {
        Locale currentLocale =  LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        String localizedErrorMessage = messageSource.getMessage(fieldError, currentLocale);

        //If the message was not found, return the most accurate field error code instead.
        //You can remove this check if you prefer to get the default error message.
        if (localizedErrorMessage.equals(fieldError.getDefaultMessage())) {
            String[] fieldErrorCodes = fieldError.getCodes();
            localizedErrorMessage = fieldErrorCodes[0];
        }

        return localizedErrorMessage;
    }
}
```

Then create a `messages.properties`:

```
Size.userWithPasswordDTO.password=The password should be between 8 and 250 characters
```

And finally adding the `@Size` and `@NotNull` annotations in the DTO file and the `@Valid` annotations in the endpoint.

The validation of the DTO works well like this, but I'm trying to find a way to handle errors in the db. For example a duplicate user.

In the official documentation, they make a class like this:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
class UserNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public UserNotFoundException(String userId) {
        super("could not find user '" + userId + "'.");
    }
}
```

That handles the exceptions thrown in the endpoints.

Now my question is, how do you make the two methods return the same DTOs?
I was also wondering if the annotations `@NotNull` and `@Size` should also be in the Entities as well as in the DTOs?

---

**EDIT**

I tried updating my `@ControllerAdvice` to handle `DataIntegrityViolationException` but it doesn't seem to work. Also, I don't know what I should put inside the `FieldError` class.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestErrorHandler {
 private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Autowired
    public RestErrorHandler(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ValidationErrorDTO processValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
        List<FieldError> fieldErrors = result.getFieldErrors();

        return processFieldErrors(fieldErrors);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
    @ResponseBody
    public ValidationErrorDTO processDuplicateError(DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
        //BindingResult result = ex.getMessage();
        List<FieldError> fieldErrors = new ArrayList<>();
        fieldErrors.add(new FieldError("duplicate", "email", "error"));

        return processFieldErrors(fieldErrors);
    }

    private ValidationErrorDTO processFieldErrors(List<FieldError> fieldErrors) {
        ValidationErrorDTO dto = new ValidationErrorDTO();

        for (FieldError fieldError: fieldErrors) {
            String localizedErrorMessage = resolveLocalizedErrorMessage(fieldError);
            dto.addFieldError(fieldError.getField(), localizedErrorMessage);
        }

        return dto;
    }

    private String resolveLocalizedErrorMessage(FieldError fieldError) {
        Locale currentLocale =  LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        String localizedErrorMessage = messageSource.getMessage(fieldError, currentLocale);

        //If the message was not found, return the most accurate field error code instead.
        //You can remove this check if you prefer to get the default error message.
        if (localizedErrorMessage.equals(fieldError.getDefaultMessage())) {
            String[] fieldErrorCodes = fieldError.getCodes();
            localizedErrorMessage = fieldErrorCodes[0];
        }

        return localizedErrorMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: same DTO you mean same object or just same class type? If you find duplicate user, did you still need the @Size validation also?

Comment: I mean that both the `@valid` and the `@responseStatus` return a `ValidationErrorDTO` Object. In case of a duplicate I don't need the `@Size` validation.

Comment: you can catch that exception and return `ValidationErrorDTO` in the catch clause right?. You need to put it in your entity only if you need to save/update entity that get the information directly from system(not from DTO), if no, then you can just put `@Size` in only one of them(dto or entity)